# Jelastic servers AngularJS ngRoute not working

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, jelastic

I have created an application using AngularJS and ngRoute for partial templates, this works fine on local Tomcat server. But  when I deploy the same application on Jelastic server following error is shown:

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: volvo.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found) http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$compile/tpload?p0=volvo.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found
```

Tried through `<a href="volvo">` and `$location.path("/volvo")` but didnt work.

Comment: Could you provide link to your web-service in Jelastic?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved issue by adding  in main html/jsp file.

Comment: It's good to hear that you found the cause of your problem.  You could make your answer more helpful for future readers by explaining *how* you diagnosed it, and in particular, which evidence will identify this problem when it's seen elsewhere.